# Create non-vlan interface with vlan-interface type name

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

I have 2 interfaces: bond0 and bond1.

bond0 is connected to a trunking port, i.e. will be assigned vlans like bond0.10
bond1 is connected to a static port for vlan 20. So as far as connectivity goes, bond1 handles just like bond0.20 would.

The problem is that I want the interface bond1 to be called bond0.20. Is that possible? From my experiments so far it seems like linux automatically assumes a devX.Y is always a vlan device and needs to be treated as such, which I don't want in this case. However all other bond0 devices like bond0.50 SHOULD be treated as vlan devices so I can't just change the vlan interface naming scheme.

Is this even possible? Can I make linux accept this situation? The goal is to achieve a completely transparent networking setup whereas all VLANs are supposed to be available as bond0.X

Comment: What do you mean you don't "want" it to act like a VLAN device? What exactly does that encompass?

Comment: I can only assume that linux takes pakets for that interface, slaps a qtag onto it and passes onto bond0, which doesnt work because that trunking port doesnt have the vlan 20 (stupid restriction of the blade enclosure).   
During boot linux exclaims:
  `Set name-type for VLAN subsystem. Should be visible in /proc/net/vlan/config` and theres no connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, a normal vlan port will tag outgoing packets, and accept only accept tagged packets, but on the "inside" it removes the tag, but I guess bridges may not follow that sort of logic. I know you can connect a machine that doesn't understand VLANs to an interface on a machine, then bridge that to a VLAN interface, the packets that arrive to the machine on the "normal" side won't have any VLAN tags, but packets heading out will.

I have no way of testing this, but I see it listed as a possible solution to what you are talking about. You will need to install [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/%E2%80%8E), and then set up rules similar to this:

`ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i bond1.20 -p 802_1Q -j DROP`

which should basically strip the 802.1q tag, and resubmit the packet to the bridge (which you may need if VLAN to VLAN bridges don't strip tags).

[This guy](http://blog.vandestreek.net/2012/10/vms-and-vlans.html) is talking about similar situations, and there are plenty of people who have similar needs to what you

Comment: apparantly you are a much better at getting meaningful search results for rather generic topics because I did not find that... so thanks. I will see how that goes.

Comment: Let me know, the results were only partially positive for me :)

Comment: thing is, I think that guy misunderstood what the DROP target does, because it doesn't magically drop the qtag. it drops the whole packet. i.e. this could work if I had the packet coming in without a qtag too (as in: duplicate). However, thank you for your assistance, but installing a package and setting up / having to maintain this rule overcomplicates rolling out new nodes so I will have to live with one interface named differently.

Comment: Yeah, quite possibly, it's not the only person I saw mentioning that, I'll link you to the search I did, then let you decide :) `ebtables+brouting+drop+802_1q+vlan-id` was what I used, have a look at this one.. http://www.rackspace.com/blog/vms-vlans-and-bridges-oh-my-part-2/